# API for getting total number of likes of a facebook page

Tags: php, facebook

I am looking for a way to keep track of my facebook page's number of likes every day. Is there an API for it? or any other way?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do it in an even easier way with the Facebook Graph API - it just returns JSON data, like so : http://graph.facebook.com/225397695229/

Where 225397695229 is the page or user ID you're referring to on FB. Just scroll to the bottom of the array and look for "likes".

**Edit - 9/4/2015 -**
Looks like an access token is required now in Facebook Graph 2.4 - so, appended to the URL would be &access_token={token_id}. Details on obtaining a Page token are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Comment: `{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}`

Comment: Looks like an access token is required now in 2.4 - so, appended to the URL would be &access_token={token} - more details in an edited answer above

Answer (score 2):

If you are the admin of the page, you should already have access to the Facebook [Insights](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/) which would provide you that information and even more!

If you want to *programmatically access* these data, you need to create an application, grant a `read_insights` and maybe `offline_access` [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) and then it's an easy [api call](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/):

```
$facebook->api("/$page_id/insights");
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure you can access the Like button on an actual Facebook page; most of the API stuff is for the facebook platform (i.e. adding a Like button to a non-facebook page.)

That said, although I've not done this you might be able to use the Graph API and get the [number of likes via JSON](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/).

EDITED TO ADD: you can use FQL ([Facebook's query language](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)) to access those properties.